# WinScard Smart Card dll 32 bit 64 bit compatibility

Tags: java, windows, dll, 32bit-64bit, winscard

I have to make use of the WinScard.dll library to access the smart card . I have a Java application that loads and makes use of this library to access the smart card .

32 Bit systems : Initially our application was written for a 32 bit Windows . Hence the following interface to the library worked well .

```
SCard INSTANCE = (SCard)Native.loadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WinSCard.dll", SCard.class);   

public int SCardEstablishContext(int iScope, Pointer pvReserved1, Pointer pvReserved2, /*OUT &long*/LongByReference rRdrlHandle);    

public int SCardGetStatusChangeA(int iHandle, int dwTimeout, /*IN/OUT*/SCardReaderState.ByReference rgReaderStates, int cReaders);
```

64 bit systems : Now while we were migrating our application for a 64 bit windows we realised that to make it work we needed to make all the iHandle long intead of int . Thus the following works

```
SCard INSTANCE = (SCard)Native.loadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\winscard", SCard.class);

public int SCardEstablishContext(int iScope, Pointer pvReserved1, Pointer pvReserved2, /*OUT &long*/LongByReference rRdrlHandle);

public int SCardGetStatusChangeA(long iHandle, int dwTimeout, /*IN/OUT*/SCardReaderState.ByReference rgReaderStates, int cReaders);



 Note: Point of interest is the first param to the SCardGetStatusChangeA api exposed by the library .
```

So now my question is this :

```
Scenario 1 :
```

- 64 bit Java VM
- 64 bit dll ( C:\Windows\System32 )
- Keep Long in the interface iHandle

Handler obtained : Correct

```
Scenario 2
```

( running on a 64 bit system but using 32 bit artifacts ) :

- 32 bit Java VM
- 32 bit dll
- Keep Long

Handler obtained : Incorrect

Shouldn't the scenario 2 be taken care automatically by the WOW64 subsystem . I read that WOW64 automatically converts the data structures so that a 32 bit application can run on a 64 bit system .

Can someone advice me on how to get my application running on both 32 & 64 bit systems without having the need to change the interface of the iHandle every time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don’t set an absolute path for the dll. Just require “WinSCard.dll,” and JNA will resolve it to the correct one for the process.
2. Use a `Pointer` for iHandle, which is either 32 or 64 bits depending on the process. See also all the “Using the Library” links from the [JNA readme](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Also consider using [JNAerator](https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/), which automatically makes JNA interfaces from the headers. If you can get it to work, it can save you a lot of time.

For the WinSCard library, I actually made a [cross-platform JNA interface](https://github.com/jnasmartcardio/jnasmartcardio/blob/master/src/main/java/jnasmartcardio/Winscard.java) which you can feel free to use or copy, in case you also want to use it with the pcsclite library on Linux or Mac.

Comment: Thanks so much . This looks certainly very promising . I will check it out as soon as when i get time out from my current sched .

Comment: THanks I was able to fix my incompatibility issues :-)

Comment: Thanks, I am using C# but this still solved my issue, specifically the second point. Changing the type for the handle from int to IntPtr did the job.